# opensips open ims and asterisk configuration for audio video calls on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, voip, opensips

I am not sure if it is a correct place for such question but unfortunately I did not find any other stackexchange site to ask this question. But I have read some similar question here like on [Open IMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380922/open-ims-in-window) and on [Asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640873/opensips-403-externa-sip-domain-forbidden-error).

My Question is, I want to make audio and video calls on my Linux based Local network(Ubuntu 12.10 based). By googling a Lot and studying I found that Open IMS, Asterisk and Open SIPS do what I need. But I am not sure what they are? and whether they fulfill my requirements? How to configure them to make audio video chat system on LAN?

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an openims server and then use a sip client to register with it. Doing so you can make audio and video calls to another sip client.

openims configuration can be done on an linux based system.

Answer (score 1):

i will describe in simple words here, although it is old thread but for any body searcing in future.
OpenSips can work as a proxy sip server, which is used for scaling purposes. But it does not have media server, which means it can route calls from A to B but can not do codec conversion or IVR for example and it is efficient, an alternative brother is Kamalio, and opensips has a web interface to configure.

Generally speaking, many people use Opensips -> Asterisk or Freeswitch.

If you want to scale more, HA Proxy is an option.